# Including .git repo in satis archive

Tags: git, composer-php, bitbucket, satis

I've setted up a private Satis server, that links to packages hosted on BitBucket.

Everything is working fine, except that I configured satis to create downloads from repos so it would be faster etc.

Problem is that I need to include .git directory from bitbucket into these package builds, but when i run satis build, the .git directories are gone from the package archive.

Is there any setting in bitbucket or satis that I can use to include .git dir in the package archive?

It is crucial for my workflow, because I want to directly edit files in /vendor folder in projects that use these packages, than make branch for these custom changes and push it back to bitbucket.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved it by using composer update --prefer-source when developing locally.